# SQL window excluding current group?

Tags: sql, hiveql

I'm trying to provide rolled up summaries of the following data including only the group in question as well as excluding the group.  I think this can be done with a window function, but I'm having problems with getting the syntax down (in my case Hive SQL).

I want the following data to be aggregated

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|    date    | product | rating |
+------------+---------+--------+
| 2018-01-01 | A       | 1      |
| 2018-01-02 | A       | 3      |
| 2018-01-20 | A       | 4      |
| 2018-01-27 | A       | 5      |
| 2018-01-29 | A       | 4      |
| 2018-02-01 | A       | 5      |
| 2017-01-09 | B       | NULL   |
| 2017-01-12 | B       | 3      |
| 2017-01-15 | B       | 4      |
| 2017-01-28 | B       | 4      |
| 2017-07-21 | B       | 2      |
| 2017-09-21 | B       | 5      |
| 2017-09-13 | C       | 3      |
| 2017-09-14 | C       | 4      |
| 2017-09-15 | C       | 5      |
| 2017-09-16 | C       | 5      |
| 2018-04-01 | C       | 2      |
| 2018-01-13 | D       | 1      |
| 2018-01-14 | D       | 2      |
| 2018-01-24 | D       | 3      |
| 2018-01-31 | D       | 4      |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

Aggregated results:

```
+------+-------+---------+----+------------+------------------+----------+
| year | month | product | ct | avg_rating | avg_rating_other | other_ct |
+------+-------+---------+----+------------+------------------+----------+
| 2018 |     1 | A       |  5 | 3.4        | 2.5              |        4 |
| 2018 |     2 | A       |  1 | 5          | NULL             |        0 |
| 2017 |     1 | B       |  4 | 3.6666667  | NULL             |        0 |
| 2017 |     7 | B       |  1 | 2          | NULL             |        0 |
| 2017 |     9 | B       |  1 | 5          | 4.25             |        4 |
| 2017 |     9 | C       |  4 | 4.25       | 5                |        1 |
| 2018 |     4 | C       |  1 | 2          | NULL             |        0 |
| 2018 |     1 | D       |  4 | 2.5        | 3.4              |        5 |
+------+-------+---------+----+------------+------------------+----------+
```

I've also considered producing two aggregates, one with the product in question and one without, but having trouble with creating the appropriate joining key.

Comment: can you explain how the calculations are performed? also show us your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select year(date), month(date), product,
       count(*) as ct, avg(rating) as avg_rating,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by year(date), month(date)) - count(*) as ct_other,
       ((sum(sum(rating)) over (partition by year(date), month(date)) - sum(rating)) /
        (sum(count(*)) over (partition by year(date), month(date)) - count(*))
       ) as avg_other
from t
group by year(date), month(date), product;
```

The rating for the "other" is a bit tricky.  You need to add everything up and subtract out the current row -- and calculate the average by doing the sum divided by the count.

Comment: Facepalm! I hadn't considered doing the math out in the query.  I kept trying to "get the right syntax".  Cheers!